# React and Electron, Chaining event handlers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

Is there a way to chain event handlers in React/JavasSript to create more functionality?

In the code below, in the div `class=resizer` I am in need of an event that allows for 'mouse down click', then 'mouse drag' before the function is executed.

```
const remote = window.require('electron').remote

const TitlebarDev = () => {

    const window = remote.getCurrentWindow()

    // allows top side resizer with click to restore
    const resizerRestore = () => {
        window.restore()
    }

    const resizerMoveRestore = () => {
        window.restore()
    }

    return (
        <div className="TitlebarDev">
            <div className="Title-BarDev">
                <div className="TitlebarDev-drag-region"></div>
                <div className="Title-BarDev__section-icon">
                </div>
                <div className="Title-BarDev__section-menubar">
                    <div><p>hi</p></div>
                </div>
                <div className="Title-BarDev__section-title">
                    <div className="section-title__title"><p>Node Debug</p></div>
                </div>
                <div className="Title-BarDev__section-windows-control">
                </div>
                <div
                    onDoubleClick={resizerRestore}
                    // needs mouse click down then drag event
                    onMouseDown={resizerMoveRestore}
                    className="resizer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div >
    )
}

export default TitlebarDev
```

Comment: If you could abbreviate your question, I'm sure you'll get answers much more quickly

Comment: Alright I cleaned it up a lot, thanks.

Comment: Just add a boolean variable that states whether the first condition (click) is met

Comment: Right in the JSX? Like a ternary operator? Can you write a little example? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, you need to keep the state of your first condition and check it upon the second event taking place.

In the following basic Vanilla JS example, I allowed the movement of the `foo` element only **after** it's clicked (and only while the mouse is still down).
For this state check I've used the `isClicked` variable.

```js
const element = document.getElementById('foo');
var isClicked = false;

element.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  isClicked = true;
});

element.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  isClicked = false;
});

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  if (isClicked) {
    element.style.left = (event.clientX - 25) + 'px';
    element.style.top = (event.clientY - 25) + 'px';
    // Please note that I arbitrarily chosen foo's
    // width and height to be 50px, hence the 25px offset
  }
});
```

```css
#foo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: tomato;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

If you're using React, you can always (and preferably) use your `state` to store these... states ;)